# Android Play Vibration from Foreground Service

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon, foreground-service, vibration

#### What I am doing:

I am making one app using Android Beacon library. I am using `RegionBootstrap` for implementation of foreground ranging and transmission of Altbeacons.

#### What I want:

I want to make the phone vibrate for suppose 500 ms when I can find a beacon within certain meters of range even when my app is running as foreground service.

#### Logic:

Logic is simple, I am performing scanning at a specific interval. Suppose I found beacons A, B, C with distance 1m, 1.5m, 0.6m. Now my threshold distance is 0.8m so I will make the phone vibrate as long as the above condition satisfies, that means user has to go out to make the distance larger so as to stop vibration.

#### Code I used:

I have found one code snippet to make the vibration

```
import android.os.Vibrator;
...
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
// Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
} else {
    //deprecated in API 26 
    v.vibrate(500);
}
```

#### Issue I am facing:

This works perfectly when my app is open. Once I close the app and the foreground service keeps scanning and transmitting, the vibration doesn't occur.

I am new to android development, kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you found any solution? I have same problem.

Comment: Please post your solution here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Try sending a local notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification) with vibration on the beacon nearby event.   This may overcome background restrictions on vibration on your phone model and give you a easy way to confirm the event is firing.   If you do not want the visual notification to stick around, you can dismiss it after a few second delay.  You can even resend the notification after a second or so to continue the vibration effect until the condition clears.

A friendly word of caution: take care that these Bluetooth distance estimates are accurate enough for your use case.  Other apps like OnePointFive have made the mistake of sending too many false  notifications, leading to very unhappy users.  You will surely want to be cautious not to repeat their mistake.  See the **Misusing Bluetooth Estimates** section of [my blog post here.](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2020/05/15/how-far-can-you-go)

Comment: I tried with notification. First of all the vibration was not coming although I used builder.setVibrate(new long[] {500}); So I used Vibrator. Notification and vibration is coming fine for few moments, after that no notification in notification drawer and no vibration. I don't know if the ranging is stopped or not although broadcast is happening as I checked with external receiver. I am not getting any log related to ranging. Does the mobile stop communicating with android studio after idle period?

Comment: Test to see if your "Android Debug Bridge" LogCat connection is active by changing the filter pull-down from "Show only selected application" to "No filters".  If the debug connection is active, you will see lots of log lines from the operating system.  If you see that and none from your app, that may mean your app has been killed by the operating system.  You may need a [foreground service](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/foreground-service.html) to stay running on stock Android 8+.  Also read [here](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2019/04/30/the-rise-of-the-nasty-forks)

Comment: Yes I am already using foreground service. I seems the battery saver option in app setting was the culprit. I selected no restriction and it is working like a charm. I am using Chinese Xiomi device.